# React Hooks: how to properly map an array with nested arrays and objects inside a select element?(new coder)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, array.prototype.map

The objective is to create a select element that maps out all the names as drop downs with react hooks, for some reason it's only rendering the first element and getting undefined errors, any code references can be provided

`````
import React from 'react';
import styles from './style.css'

const Traveler = () => {
    const travelers = [
        { title: "What kind of traveler are you?", name: [
            "Adrenaline Addicts", "Culture Lovers", "Aquatic adventures", "Beach enthusiasts", "Adventure seekers",
            "Party hoppers", "Motor fans"
        ] }
    ]

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <select type="text" name="Transportation" className={styles.select}>
                <option value="Transportation" className={styles.field} value={travelers[0].title}></option>  
                { travelers.map((item, index) => {
                    return(
                        <option>{item[0].name[index]}</option>
                    );
                })
            }
            </select> 

        </React.Fragment>
    );

}

export default Traveler;
````
`````

Comment: I am not seeing you using `hook`s anywhere

Comment: You're running map on travelers--there's only one. Are you trying to map over the array in the "name" property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the mapping over the array. You would need two map functions, one for the `travelers` array and the second one which maps over the `name` array inside each traveler. It would look something like this.

```
{ travelers.map((traveler) => {
  return(
    <option value="Transportation" className={styles.field} value={traveler.title}></option>  
          {traveler.name.map((name) => <option>{name}</option>}
  );
})
```

Comment: @goto1  you're absolutely right.I mean that we're using functional components like we do on hooks instead of class components.

Comment: @davenewton Yes. trying to map over the name property, looks like it's about using a second map function to resolve.